# Ajustar colunas de um DBGrid

Tags: delphi, redimensionamento, dbgrid

Estou com um problema para pegar uma função onde faça o mesmo que o Excel (Redimensionar colunas).

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem o espaçamento das colunas, enormes e sem necessidade.

Gostaria de uma solução em forma de função para conseguir realizar o `REDIMENSIONAMENTO` das colunas após a busca.

No caso deveria ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma função que faça algo parecido?

Comment: Isto é uma afirmação ou uma pergunta? Amigo somo um Q&A aqui, se isto for uma resposta recomendo que poste no campo de resposta após formular uma pergunta, você já é membro faz um tempo e acredito que deva saber como a comunidade funciona, no entanto recomendo que leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amigos, consegui resolver.

Segue abaixo:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.AjustarColunas(DBGrid : TDBgrid);
var
  ColumnCount, RowCount : integer;
  DataSetTemp : TDataSet;
  DataSourceTemp : TDataSource;
  contCol, contRow : integer;
  AValue : integer;
  MStrValue, AStrValue : string;
begin
  //captura colunas do dbgrid 
  ColumnCount := DBGrid.Columns.Count;
  //verifica se existem colunas
  if (ColumnCount = 0) then Exit;
  //verifica se o TDataSet do DataSource referenciado no DBGrid está ativo (haha)
  if not DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Active  then Exit;

  //captura em variáveis temporárias o dataset e datasource, e também a quantidade de linhas que sua query retornou no record count
  DataSetTemp := DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet;
  DataSourceTemp := DBGrid.DataSource;
  //esta instrução foi feita para evitar que o usuário veja o processo de redimensionamento do dbgrid.  
  DBGrid.DataSource := nil;
  RowCount := DataSetTemp.RecordCount;

  //varre todas as colunas do dbgrid
  for contCol := 0 to ColumnCount-1 do
  begin
    AValue := 0;
    AStrValue := '';

    DataSetTemp.First;
    //Seta o primeiro valor como o TÍTULO da coluna para evitar que os campos fiquem "invisíveis", quando não houver campo preenchido.
    MStrValue := DBGrid.Columns[contCol].Title.Caption;
    while not DataSetTemp.Eof do
    begin
    //captura valor e o length do campo atual 
      AValue := Length(DataSetTemp.FieldByName(DBGrid.Columns[contCol].FieldName).AsString);
      AStrValue := DataSetTemp.FieldByName(DBGrid.Columns[contCol].FieldName).AsString;
      DataSetTemp.Next;

      //verifica se a próxima variável é maior que a anterior
      //e mantém a maior.
      if length(MStrValue) < AValue then
        MStrValue := AStrValue;
    end;

    //seta a largura atual com o tamanho do campo maior capturado       
    //anteriormente (Observe que há uma conversão de texto para Width, 
    //isto é para capturar o valor real da largura do texto.)
    DBGrid.Columns[contCol].Width := Canvas.TextWidth(MStrValue)+15;
  end;

  //DataSource novamente referenciado, para evitar Acess Violation.
  DBGrid.DataSource := DataSourceTemp;
end;
```

Método de uso:

```
//Após o Open da query, utilizar desta forma; 
AjustarColunas(DBGrid1);
```

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47306)

Comment: Entendo. Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia explicar o código? É legal dar algo pronto, mas muito vem aqui pro caso de estudo, seria legal explicar o seu código :) . Vou dar +1 pra ti, pelo seu esforço no código!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, segue o código comentado!